# Moving a surface from one side of an object to the other

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make a minecraft mouth. If I went simple I would have no questions, or if there was a tutorial or a tutorial for blender at least. But me being me I have to make one of if not the best rig out there. I am new to blender so to all of you who answer my questions I appreciate it for taking your time to answer all these simple questions for one rig.

Here is the mouth before the move (The program the guy did this in is Maya, but most things are the same):
[image]

Then here is the mouth after the move:
[image]

Comment: Do you want this as part of the rig, or do you want to know how to move it with modelling tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select the faces for mouth, press <kbd>Y</kbd> to split;

[image]

- Press <kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>X</kbd> > <kbd>-1</kbd> to give it a mirrored scale along its X axis. Done. (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > <kbd>X</kbd>)

[image]

P.S.: I'm not so sure about the word "rig" you mentioned here, suppose you are trying to animate it, then I suggest using Blender's ShapeKey feature in this case. [Demo file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/25212) included.

Comment: I am going to be animating the mouth but first I need to do the inside.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the title, I assume you want to do this with modeling tools.

[Leon Cheung's solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/4842/599) is good, except in your original screenshot there are no faces here:

[image]

So selecting those faces and the inset faces and then mirroring will not work.

Instead you could use the [*Snapping features*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap_to_Mesh):

> There are two types of snap operations that you can use in Blender. The first type snaps your selection or cursor to a given point while the second type is used during transformations (translate, rotate, scale) and snaps your selection to elements within the scene.

## [Transform Snapping:](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap_to_Mesh)

1. With the inset selected, press <kbd>Y</kbd> to separate:

   [image]
2. Enable [*Snapping*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap_to_Mesh) ([image: icon]) and [*Auto-merge editing*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Vertices#AutoMerge_Editing) ([image: icon]) in the *Header*, and set the [*Snap Element*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap_to_Mesh#Snap_Element) to *Vertex*:

   [image]
3. Press <kbd>G</kbd> to grab and move the cursor over one of the target vertices:

   [image]

The separated selection will be automatically merged with the overlapping vertices by *Auto-Merge*, eliminating the need to use <kbd>W</kbd>*> Specials > Remove doubles*.

## [Snapping with the 3D cursor:](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point/3D_Cursor#Positioning_the_3D_cursor)

Another way to do this is with the [3D cursor](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Pivot_Point/3D_Cursor):

1. Select the edgeloop around the extruded region and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*> Cursor to selected*:

   [image]
2. Select the separated region and press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>*> Selection to cursor (Offset)*:

   [image]
3. (If you have *Auto-Merge Editing* enabled this step in unnecessary) Select at least the overlapping duplicate vertices (I most cases it's fine to select all) and press <kbd>W</kbd>*> Remove Doubles*:

   [image]

   [image]